# App ionic 3 com tela branca

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Eu gerei um app ionic tabs não mudei nada, deixei como estava, depois criei um apk, quando vou rodar o app no android ele fica com uma tela branca depois do splash screen.

Comment: Debuga o aplicativo e ve se está com algum erro no console.